# No Android item under: Eclipse>Window> Preferences

Tags: installation, android

I have installed the android SDK, but It does not show in windows>preferences. I have re-installed both the SDK and eclipse but the same problem persists

I am on Ubuntu 10.4 and Eclipse Helios.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Eclipse as root then installing Android SDK fixed this problem.